# React native animate buttom tab bar icons with reanimated 2?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I need to animate selected tab icon and I use reanimated 2 to achieve that. below is the concept of my custom bottom tab bar:
[image]

as you can see the third tab is currently selected, my goal is to position the selected tab icon 15px to the left (I mean translateX to the value of -15) and after selecting another tab the Icon of previous tab will go back to the center (translateX to the 0). I tried some ways but no luck, here is what I implemented so far:

```js
    const animateIcon = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        return {
            transform: [
                {
                    translateX: withSpring(-15),
                },
            ],
        };
    });


const renderButtons = useMemo(() => {
        return tabs.map((tab: {name: string; id: number}) => { // a map over tabs array which has object's of each tab name and date
            return (
                <Box
                    key={tab.id}
                    alignItems='center'
                    flexDirection='column'
                    style={styles.overlay}
                >
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                        onPress={() => onPress(tab.name, tab.id)}
                        style={styles.button}
                    >
                        <AnimatedBox style={[tab.id === currentRouteIndex ? animateIcon : null]}> //here I animate the icon if id of the tab is the same as current selected tab
                            <Home fill={'#000'} size={20} />
                        </AnimatedBox>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </Box>
            );
        });
    }, [animateIcon, onPress, styles.button, styles.overlay, tabs]);
```

can anyone give me a hint on this? above method doesn't work and it cause weird behavior

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to have a `sharedValue` or `derivedValue` that will trigger the animation from `0` to `-15px` an viceversa.

Then you can create a component to handle the animation:

```
export function AnimatedIcon({ children, focused } : { children: React.ReactNode; focused: number })  {
 const translate = useDerivedValue(() => {
  return withTiming(focused, { duration: 500 });
 });

 const rStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
 const translateX = interpolate(translate.value, [0, 1], [0, -15]);

 return {
   transform: [{ translateX }],
 };
});

return <Animated.View style={rStyle}>{children}</Animated.View>;
```